# For any $k \gt 3$, if $n!+k$ is a perfect power then does there exist any $n\gt k$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, perfect-powers

A while ago, I asked a similar question [For any $k \gt 1$, if $n!+k$ is a square then will $n \le k$ always be true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499670/for-any-k-gt-1-if-nk-is-a-square-then-will-n-le-k-always-be-true) where users mathworker21 and WE Tutorial School proved that for non-square $k$, $n\le k$ is always true when $n!+k$ is sqaure.

Recently I got the idea to check if the property is true for all perfect powers and using PARI, I observed that if,
$$n!+k=a^b$$
where $n, k, a, b\in \Bbb{N}$, $k\gt 3$ and $b\ge 2$, then $n\le k$ is always true. In search for a counter-example, I covered a range of $k\le 2500$ and $n\le 10^4$ for each $k$ and found none.

So my question is,

> If true, can we prove/partially prove that $n\le k$ always holds? If false, then what is the smallest counter-example where $n\gt k$?

Comment: If $k=rs$ with $1<r<s$ and $n!+k=a^b$ with $b\geq2$, then by the same argument as in the linked question
$$\frac{a^b}{k}=\frac{n!}{k}+1=k\frac{n!}{rsk}+1,$$
which shows that $\tfrac{a^b}{k}$ is coprime to $k$, so $k=c^b$ for some positive integer $c$, and also
$$\frac{n!}{k}+1=d^b,$$
for some positive integer $d$. We also get the expression
 $$n!=a^b-c^b=c^b(d^b-1).$$

Comment: In the remaining case, either $k$ is prime $p$ or $k$ is the square of a prime $p$. If $k\leq n$ then $p$ divides $n!$ and hence also
$$n!+k=a^b,$$
so $p^b$ divides $n!+k$. If $b=2$ then the linked question settles it. If $b>2$ then $p^3$ divides $a^b$ but not $k$, hence $p^3$ does not divide $n!$. This means $n<3p$ and so we arrive at a contradiction if $k\geq3p$, i.e. if $k=p^2$ with $p\neq2$. This leaves the cases when $k$ is prime and when $k=4$.

Comment: In particular, my first comment shows that the factors of $c$ are 'small' compared to $n$; if $p\mid c$ then $p^b\mid n!$ so $bp\leq n$ (or $p\leq b$). On the other hand, the factors of $d$ are 'large' compared to $n$; if $p\mid d$ then $p>n$ because $d$ is coprime to $n!$.

Comment: I checked upto $n=7\ 000$ , but with all $k<n$ , no counterexample

Comment: Dear downvoters please explain what is wrong with this question?

Comment: whoah, why did this get $4$ (!!) downvotes?