# Can $n!+16$ be a perfect square when $n\geq5$?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

Can $n!+16$ be a perfect square?

I think $n!+16$ can be a perfect square, since $n!+16$ is $0 \mod 4$, and always $1 \mod 3$ ( when n is $> 5$), and always $5 \mod 11$ ( when $n$ is $> 11$).

But when I tried to find if are there any perfect squares form of $n!+16$, I didn't succeed.

Are there any perfect squares form of $n!+16$?

Comment: This might be very difficult to solve. The similar case $n!+1$ is unknown.

Comment: For a non-negative integer $n\le 10^4$ , $n!+16$ is not even a perfect power which brute force with PARI/GP reveals.

Comment: See [For any $k \gt 1$, if $n!+k$ is a square then will $n \le k$ always be true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499670/for-any-k-gt-1-if-nk-is-a-square-then-will-n-le-k-always-be-true), the square case is generally unresolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the Diophantine equation
$$
n!+k=m^2
$$
is "easy" for $k$ being a non-square integer and hard for $k$ being a perfect square. In fact, if $k$ is not a square it follows that $n\le k$. In this case, for small $k$, we only have to check a few possible values for $n$. The most famous case, where $k$ is a perfect square is the [Brocard equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem) $n!+1=m^2$, which is unsolved until today.

For a reference see the following post with very informative answers:

[For any $k \gt 1$, if $n!+k$ is a square then will $n \le k$ always be true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499670/for-any-k-gt-1-if-nk-is-a-square-then-will-n-le-k-always-be-true)